# Como tomar el header de una pagina con Web Scraping PHP

Tags: php, html

es que necesito una manera de tomar el header de una pagina en especifico por medio de web scraping.

La pagina que tengo es https://www.nexttrucksales.com/ y quiero solo tomar el header
el codigo actual que tengo solo copia la pagina, pero quiero solo tomar el header.

```
<?php 
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.nexttrucksales.com/'); //Convierte la información de la URL en cadena
echo $html;


?>
```

Comment: Intenta con [get_headers()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.get-headers.php)

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigos ya encontre la solución.

```
<?php 
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.nexttrucksales.com/');

$start = stripos($html, '<header');

$end = stripos($html, '</header>', $offset = $start);

$length = $end - $start;

$htmlSection = substr($html, $start, $length);

echo $htmlSection;
?>
```

Aqui lo unico que se hace es por medio de la funcion stripos que tome cadenas especificas de un html y que las imprima, ya dependiendo si tiene librerias de diseño tambien debe estar dentro de esas o con otra funcion igual poner las librerias o manualmente se puede.